# Finding Binomial Expansion as x approaches infinity of a function

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the series that is valid for
$(x^3 + x^2 + 1)^{\frac{1}{3}} - (x^2 + x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$
as x approaches infinity.

The question says this should be possible using the binomial expansion but I can't work out how to do that.

Comment: Are you familiar with expanding out $ ( 1 + x) ^{1/3}$? IE the fractional binomial theorem. If so, you can show that $ ( x^ 3 + x^2 + 1) ^ {1/3} = x+1/3 - 1/9x + 32/81x^2 - \ldots $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $a^6-b^6=(a-b)(a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5)$
- $(x^3+x^2+1)^\frac13=x(1+1/x+1/x^3)^\frac13$ and similar to the $\frac12$ term

Comment: Thank you! I think I have an idea now, I'll give it a go and mark you as the answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^3 + x^2 + 1)^{\frac{1}{3}} - (x^2 + x)^{\frac{1}{2}}=x\left(1+\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x  \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Now use
$$(1+\epsilon )^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{n}}{n}\epsilon^n$$

Fot the first term, make $n=\frac 13$ and $\epsilon= \frac{x^2+1}{x^3}$; for the second , make $n=\frac 12$ and $\epsilon= \frac{1}{x}$.

Expand a little the powers of $\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}$ and you will have
$$(x^3 + x^2 + 1)^{\frac{1}{3}} - (x^2 + x)^{\frac{1}{2}}=-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{72 x}+\frac{431}{1296 x^2}-\frac{6977}{31104
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$

Try for $x=1000$; the truncated series will give
$$-\frac{5183557662977}{31104000000000} =\color{red}{-0.166652445440}361$$ while
$$\sqrt[3]{1001000001}-10 \sqrt{10010}=\color{red}{-0.166652445440174}$$